# Android App Debugging Problem: App Keeps Stopping on Emulator

Tags: android, flutter, debugging

fellow developers!

I'm facing a rather puzzling issue with my Android app development and could use some insights from the community. I've successfully been debugging my iOS app with no problems, but when it comes to Android, I've hit a roadblock.

**The Problem:**
When attempting to debug my Android app on the emulator, the app starts installing as expected, but once it's launched on the emulator, it keeps stopping, and I'm left scratching my head. The console shows that the installation process goes smoothly, but the emulator keeps displaying the "App Keeps Stopping" message.

[Check the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMZBQ.jpg)
[Here what emulator shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vcyS.jpg)

**What I've Tried So Far:**
I've gone through various troubleshooting steps, including checking Logcat for error messages, reviewing my code, and verifying emulator settings. However, the issue persists.

**System Information:**

- I'm using Android Studio for development.
- My emulator is running the latest Android SDK.
- My computer has sufficient resources, including RAM and CPU.

If you've encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions for troubleshooting steps, I would greatly appreciate your input. Has anyone experienced this issue before, and if so, how did you resolve it?

Please share your insights, advice, or any solutions you might have. Your assistance would be incredibly valuable in getting my Android app development back on track.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you tried a different emulator with different SDK version? Also, debugging on a physical device?

Comment: If an app stops o crashes usually you should check `adb logcat` for errors of that app. Please edit your question and include the relevant messages from logcat (as text not as screenshot).